# Best way in Doctrine to load only entities which have attached entities

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, group-by

I have an entity, let's call it `Foo` and a second one `Bar`

`Foo` can (but doesn't have to) have one or multiple `Bar` entries assigned. It looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $bars;
```

I now would like to load in one case only `Foo` entities that have at least one `Bar` entity assigned. Previously, there was one `foreach` loop to traverse all `Foo` entries and if it had assigned entries, the `Foo` entry got assigned to an array.

My current implementation is in the `FooRepository` a function called `findIfTheresBar` which looks like this:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('e')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'e')
        /* some where stuff here */
        ->addOrderBy('e.name', 'ASC')
        ->join('e.bars', 'b')
        ->groupBy('e.id');
```

Is this the correct way to load such entries? Is there a better (faster) way? It kind of feels as if it should have a `having(...)` in the query.

---

**EDIT:**
I've investigated it a little further. The query should return 373 out of 437 entries.

- *Version 1:* only using `join()`, this loaded 373 entries in 7.88ms
- *Version 2:* using `join()` and `having()`, this loaded 373 entries in 8.91ms
- *Version 3:* only using `leftJoin()`, this loaded all 437 entries (which isn't desired) in 8.05ms
- *Version 4:* using `leftJoin()` and `having()`, this loaded 373 entries in 8.14ms

Since *Version 1* which only uses an `innerJoin` as @Chausser pointed out, is the fastest, I will stick to that one.

Note: I'm not saying *Version 1* will be the fastest in all scenarios and on every hardware, so kind of a follow up question, does anybody know about a performance comparison?

Comment: Unless you're filtering something in `/* some where stuff here */` part that query will still give you all `foo` entities and not just the ones with a `bar` attached - there's indeed a `->having('COUNT(b) > 0')` missing.

Comment: Hmm probably those entries I've checked where just by coincident gone. Will try it later.

Comment: This is probably best way to do this. Also I don't think that what ccKep said is true since you've done a `join()` and not a `leftJoin()`. To be sure, you can check final SQL query in Symfony profiler.

Comment: As `join()` is just basically an alias for `innerJoin()` that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this answer for more information on how SQL JOINs work:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/1307183

Using a `join`, which is an alias of `innerJoin`, is exactly what you want.  This only returns records where entries exist in both `Foo` and `Bar` - aka where the association/attached entity exists.  This calls `INNER JOIN` in SQL, which, if your database structure is defined correctly, is the absolute best and fastest way to get the data you want.

Using a `leftJoin` calls `LEFT JOIN` in SQL, which returns all records from `Foo`, even if there is no `Bar` associated with it (for example, where `bar_id` in your `foo` table would be `null`).

You have no reason to use `having()` in any of the above scenarios you described.  If you want to filter further you would do that with a `->addWhere()` function.  Using the `having()` clause is something you would only want to do if you were selecting aggregate data in your original query (like `SELECT SUM(field) AS sum_field`).